# How to ask for user input and amend shell script?

Tags: shell, loops, input

I am creating a Loop that will let me rsync files from a variable directory one level above and then bzip those files at every level, infinitely until I press CTRL+C. So far this is what I have for the shell script:

```
while :

do

        rsync -av ../gene/ .
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*
        echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
        sleep 1
done
```

What I would like to have happen is it ask for the directory that it should rsync from. The directory is not always gene and is variable, so user input is a must. Any help with this and possibly cleaning the script up is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myFolder=$1;

echo "Working on "$myFolder;

while :

do

        rsync -av $myFolder .
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*/*
        bzip2 -kv */*
        echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
        sleep 1
done
```

save with the name **`someprogram.sh`** and excute (if you are there)

```
bash ./someprogram.sh someFolder
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: If I run this from the folder I want to rsync information to it is looking at /currentFolder/someFolder. Is there any way to get it to rsync from one level above on someFolder?